# How to delete items from a list of dictionairies in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have a list of dict (named 'result'). The list Looks like that:

```py
result=[{'label': 'person', 'confidence': 0.8308641, 'topleft': {'x': 1236, 'y': 335}, 'bottomright': {'x': 1439, 'y': 784}}, 
{'label': 'car', 'confidence': 0.510271, 'topleft': {'x': 281, 'y': 499}, 'bottomright': {'x': 359, 'y': 543}}]
```

I want to delete all the items which are 'car'

```py
for item in result[:]:
     if item['label'] is 'car':
        result.remove(item)
print(result)
```

But it changes nothing...What I did wrong?

Comment: `result = [i for i in result if i["label"] != 'car']` ?

Comment: to be honest, seems like your original code works as well... https://ideone.com/DA0Jib

Comment: Your code does work. It's wrong (you should use the equality operator `==`, not the identity operator `is`) and unpythonic (the pythonic way is to build a filtered list as shown by Rakesh - unless your list is really huge of course but then that's another issue), but it does work.

Comment: NB: it does work on CPython up to 3.6.8 at least... If you're using another implementation, then your issue is obviously the wrong use of the identity operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in comparison operator: change `is` to `==` and everything will work properly.

> Python has the two comparison operators `==` and `is`. At first sight they seem to be the same, but actually they are not. `==` compares two variables based on their actual value. In contrast, the `is` operator compares two variables based on the object id and returns `True` if the two variables refer to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

Use `==` or `!=` to do a string comparison. You can use a simple list comprehension here.

**Ex:**

```
result=[{'label': 'person', 'confidence': 0.8308641, 'topleft': {'x': 1236, 'y': 335}, 'bottomright': {'x': 1439, 'y': 784}},{'label': 'car', 'confidence': 0.510271, 'topleft': {'x': 281, 'y': 499}, 'bottomright': {'x': 359, 'y': 543}}]

result = [i for i in result if i["label"] != 'car']
print(result)
```